# Windows 10 - Set updates download time

Tags: windows-update, windows-10

would it be possible to change scheduled time of download in Windows 10?
Every day one of my Windows 10 machines start to download updates that saturate my bandwidth. I want to teach them to download only at night.

Comment: Isn't your Group Policy working?

Comment: Can you indicate me a group policy about this issue? I find only one for choose installation time not download time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not yet. There is a feature request running for that one (but its 6 months old+)

If you got a proxy or a firewall that you can add rule with timeset, you could block them that way to make a temporary solution.

Comment: I will try like this.
Many thanks!